# Diophantine Equation With Varying Exponents

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am considering the following Diophantine Equation - the approach I tried became the study of too many different cases - so many that I left it and tried to find an easier way. I wonder if anyone could shed any further light on the matter. The equation is interesting since it has 3 different exponents.
$$ a^2 +b^3 = c^4 $$
$a$, $b$, $c$, are any integers. The approach I mentioned began by subtracting the $a^2$ on both sides and factoring the difference of two squares -  but as I said, it quickly became very tedious.

Comment: What are we seeking? A solution where none of the variables is $0$? Infinitely many solutions of this type? All solutions? There are other possibilities.

Comment: All solutions. The case when one of the variables is 0 included, although these are trivial and easy to deduce.

Comment: see Lemma 3.2.7 p.22 here http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~nbruin/thesis.pdf . Just set $(a,b,c)\rightarrow (a,-b,c)$ in the set of solutions.

Comment: Really, so one can obtain a non-trivial solution from those parametric solutions?

Comment: I was thinking maybe the only solutions are the trivial solutions, but that was just a wild guess.

Comment: Ah! That link is very helpful yes. Thank you very much 111. How did you first come across that document?

Comment: I needed it,in my phd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an infinite family of solutions,

$$\big(4q^2(p^2-2)\big)^2+(4dq^2)^3  = (2pq)^4$$

where $p,q$ solve the *Pell equation* $p^2-d^3q^2=1$. If you want the "reversed" form,

$$p^4 + (q^2-1)^3 = (q^3+q)^2$$

where $p^2-3q^2=1$. And an amazing one by Enrico Jabara,

$$(2^{88}7^{47}n^4)^3 + (2^{92}7^{49}n)^4 + (2^{32}7^{17}n^4)^5 + (2^8 7^4n^4)^7 + (n^4-2^{52}7^{28})^8 = (n^4+2^{52}7^{28})^8$$

which he probably found by expanding,

$$(an^4)^3 + (bn)^4 + (cn^4)^5 + (dn^4)^7 + (n^4-e)^8 = (n^4+e)^8$$

collecting powers of $n$, and solving for $a,b,c,d,e$.

Answer (score -1):

I thought it possible to write a solution without using equations Pell.

$$a^2+b^3=c^4$$

If you make this change.

$$p=tz(2zk^2+t)$$

$$s=tzk^2(2zk^2-t)$$

The result of such decision.

$$a=sp^3$$

$$b=2tzk^2p^2$$

$$c=kp^2$$

Where the number $t,z,k$ - integers and set us.  You may need after you get the numbers, divided by the common divisor.